# Updating driver for DWA 160 ubuntu for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have used this website to install the driver for DWA-160

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/229-ubuntu-precise-dlink-dwa160-revb2

Lately I've been having some trouble with updating eclipse so it no longer recognizes my ADT plugin and I need to reinstall. Will there be a way in the future to reinstall these drivers for the DWA-160 that is much easier and less time consuming?

I made a script to install all the software I want like VLC etc, but to follow the guide above everytime I need a fresh install of ubuntu sounds tiring